# (Conda)Tensorflow-gpu installing

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda

My goal is to use gpu(GE FORCE GTX 850M). I have tried according to this guide(https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/tasks/tensorflow/). Tensoflow 2.8 is installed and keras also. But when I execute the test code, the output is as below. It must be that the code does not or cannot use gpu. What went wrong?

```
(my_tf) PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> python -c "import tensorflow as tf;print(tf.reduce_sum(tf.random.normal([1000, 1000])))"

2022-03-01 23:30:30.626829: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN)to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
```

※ Below is all the installed packages(Name/Version/Build/Channel) at my C:\Anaconda3

```
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0                    py38_0
_py-xgboost-mutex         2.0                       cpu_0
absl-py                   0.15.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
anaconda-client           1.9.0            py38haa95532_0
anaconda-navigator        2.1.2            py38haa95532_0
anyio                     3.5.0            py38haa95532_0
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py38h2bbff1b_0
astunparse                1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports                 1.1                pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backports.tempfile        1.0                pyhd3eb1b0_1
backports.weakref         1.0.post1                  py_1
beautifulsoup4            4.10.0             pyh06a4308_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
bottleneck                1.3.2            py38h2a96729_1
brotli                    1.0.9                ha925a31_2
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h2bbff1b_1003
bs4                       0.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
bzip2                     1.0.8                he774522_0
ca-certificates           2021.10.26           haa95532_4
cachetools                5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2021.10.8        py38haa95532_2
cffi                      1.15.0           py38h2bbff1b_1
chardet                   4.0.0           py38haa95532_1003
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
chime                     0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
clyent                    1.2.2                    py38_1
colorama                  0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda                     4.11.0           py38haa95532_0
conda-build               3.21.7           py38haa95532_1
conda-content-trust       0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-env                 2.6.0                haa95532_1
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py38h8cc25b3_1
conda-repo-cli            1.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-token               0.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
conda-verify              3.4.2                      py_1
console_shortcut          0.1.1                         4
cryptography              3.4.8            py38h71e12ea_0
cupy                      7.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
datetime                  4.3                      pypi_0    pypi
debugpy                   1.5.1            py38hd77b12b_0
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
descartes                 1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_4
entrypoints               0.3                      py38_0
fastrlock                 0.8                      pypi_0    pypi
filelock                  3.4.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
flatbuffers               2.0                      pypi_0    pypi
fonttools                 4.25.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
freetype                  2.10.4               hd328e21_0
future                    0.18.2                   py38_1
gast                      0.5.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
glob2                     0.7                pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-auth               2.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.6                    pypi_0    pypi
google-pasta              0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
graphviz                  2.38                 hfd603c8_2
grpcio                    1.44.0                   pypi_0    pypi
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
icu                       58.2                 ha925a31_3
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
imap-tools                0.34.0                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib-metadata        4.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib_metadata        4.8.2                hd3eb1b0_0
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          haa95532_3556
ipykernel                 6.4.1            py38haa95532_1
ipython                   7.31.1           py38haa95532_0
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1
jedi                      0.18.1           py38haa95532_1
jinja2                    2.11.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
joblib                    1.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jpeg                      9d                   h2bbff1b_0
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jsonschema                3.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
jupyter_client            7.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyter_core              4.9.1            py38haa95532_0
jupyter_server            1.13.5             pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyterlab                3.2.9              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
jupyterlab_server         2.10.3             pyhd3eb1b0_1
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
keras                     2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
kiwisolver                1.3.2            py38hd77b12b_0
libarchive                3.4.2                h5e25573_0
libclang                  13.0.0                   pypi_0    pypi
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7
liblief                   0.10.1               ha925a31_0
libpng                    1.6.37               h2a8f88b_0
libtiff                   4.2.0                hd0e1b90_0
libwebp                   1.2.2                h2bbff1b_0
libxgboost                1.5.0                hd77b12b_1
libxml2                   2.9.12               h0ad7f3c_0
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h2bbff1b_1
markdown                  3.3.6                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.0.1            py38h2bbff1b_0
matplotlib                3.5.1            py38haa95532_0
matplotlib-base           3.5.1            py38hd77b12b_0
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2
menuinst                  1.4.18           py38h59b6b97_0
mistune                   0.8.4           py38he774522_1000
mizani                    0.7.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640
mkl-service               2.4.0            py38h2bbff1b_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py38h277e83a_0
mkl_random                1.2.2            py38hf11a4ad_0
mouseinfo                 0.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
multitasking              0.0.10                   pypi_0    pypi
munkres                   1.1.4                      py_0
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py38_1
nbclassic                 0.3.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbclient                  0.5.11             pyhd3eb1b0_0
nbconvert                 6.1.0            py38haa95532_0
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
notebook                  6.4.8            py38haa95532_0
numexpr                   2.8.1            py38hb80d3ca_0
numpy                     1.22.2                   pypi_0    pypi
numpy-base                1.21.5           py38hc2deb75_0
oauthlib                  3.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
olefile                   0.46               pyhd3eb1b0_0
openssl                   1.1.1m               h2bbff1b_0
opt-einsum                3.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0
palettable                3.3.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.4.1            py38hd77b12b_0
pandas-datareader         0.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
patsy                     0.5.2            py38haa95532_1
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    8.4.0            py38hd45dc43_0
pip                       22.0.3                   pypi_0    pypi
pkginfo                   1.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
plotnine                  0.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
powershell_shortcut       0.0.1                         3
prometheus_client         0.13.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0
protobuf                  3.19.4                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.8.0            py38h2bbff1b_1
py-lief                   0.10.1           py38ha925a31_0
py-xgboost                1.5.0            py38haa95532_1
pyasn1                    0.4.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pyautogui                 0.9.52                   pypi_0    pypi
pybithumb                 1.0.21                   pypi_0    pypi
pycosat                   0.6.3            py38h2bbff1b_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygetwindow               0.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyjwt                     2.1.0            py38haa95532_0
pykorbit                  0.1.10                   pypi_0    pypi
pymsgbox                  1.0.9                    pypi_0    pypi
pyopenssl                 19.1.0                   py38_0
pyparsing                 3.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyperclip                 1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.9.2            py38hd77b12b_6
pyqt5                     5.15.4                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-qt5                 5.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqt5-sip                 12.9.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqtchart                 5.15.4                   pypi_0    pypi
pyqtchart-qt5             5.15.2                   pypi_0    pypi
pyrect                    0.1.4                    pypi_0    pypi
pyrsistent                0.18.0           py38h196d8e1_0
pyscreeze                 0.1.26                   pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38haa95532_0
python                    3.8.12               h6244533_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-graphviz           0.16               pyhd3eb1b0_1
python-libarchive-c       2.9                pyhd3eb1b0_1
pytweening                1.0.3                    pypi_0    pypi
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyupbit                   0.2.21                   pypi_0    pypi
pywin32                   302              py38h827c3e9_1
pywinauto                 0.6.8                    pypi_0    pypi
pywinpty                  2.0.2            py38h5da7b33_0
pyyaml                    6.0              py38h2bbff1b_1
pyzmq                     22.3.0           py38hd77b12b_2
qt                        5.9.7            vc14h73c81de_0
qtpy                      1.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
requests                  2.27.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
rsa                       4.8                      pypi_0    pypi
ruamel_yaml               0.15.100         py38h2bbff1b_0
scikit-learn              1.0.2            py38hf11a4ad_1
scipy                     1.7.3            py38h0a974cb_0
selenium                  3.141.0                  pypi_0    pypi
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
setuptools                58.0.4           py38haa95532_0
sip                       4.19.13          py38hd77b12b_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
sniffio                   1.2.0            py38haa95532_1
soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sqlite                    3.37.2               h2bbff1b_0
statsmodels               0.13.0           py38h2bbff1b_0
tensorboard               2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-data-server   0.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.8.1                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow                2.8.0                    pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem 0.24.0                   pypi_0    pypi
termcolor                 1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
terminado                 0.13.1           py38haa95532_0
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tf-estimator-nightly      2.8.0.dev2021122109          pypi_0    pypi
threadpoolctl             2.2.0              pyh0d69192_0
tk                        8.6.11               h2bbff1b_0
tornado                   6.1              py38h2bbff1b_0
tqdm                      4.62.3             pyhd3eb1b0_1
traitlets                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
typing-extensions         3.10.0.2             hd3eb1b0_0
typing_extensions         3.10.0.2           pyh06a4308_0
ujson                     4.0.2            py38hd77b12b_0
urllib3                   1.26.8             pyhd3eb1b0_0
utils                     1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1
websocket-client          0.58.0           py38haa95532_4
websockets                9.1                      pypi_0    pypi
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
widgetsnbextension        3.5.2            py38haa95532_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py38haa95532_0
wincertstore              0.2              py38haa95532_2
winpty                    0.4.3                         4
xgboost                   1.5.0            py38haa95532_1
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_0
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0
yfinance                  0.1.66                   pypi_0    pypi
zipp                      3.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h8cc25b3_4
zstd                      1.4.9                h19a0ad4_0
```

Answer (score 2):

The anaconda guide looks outdated, because since Tensorflow 2.0, tensorflow and tensorflow-gpu are merged into one.

If you are using Tensorflow 2, I would advise you this guide https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu which has worked for me (do not download the latest cuDNN SDK version which is bugged but the one indicated in the tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

In this guide https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows, there are version configuration .It helped.